# In Yii how to show data of two table

Tags: yii

I have two table

```
User
---------
id
username
password
level
company_id


Company
-----------
id
name
website
```

Now I want to show user list(Gridview) with their company name WHERE company_id = 1

Comment: Use a relation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr
In CGridView you can then replace company_id with company.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use relations in your models. After creating your models via `gii` go to your `User` model and change `relations` method like below:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'company'=>array(self::HAS_ONE,'Company','company_id')
    );
}
```

Then, you can do like below:

```
$user=User::model()->findByPk(10); //for example user with id=10
echo $user->company->name; //it returns the relative company name
```

**Notes:**

- I assumed that each user has one company. That's why I wrote `self::HAS_ONE`
- In `CGridView` you can do : `$data->company->name`
- `company` is just a name for relation, but the `Company` is the related model
- Yii has a powerful and comprehensive document. So, it is better to take a look at its official document. [Relational Query Options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options)